# cellspace: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\ecolumn): `c' used. \end{tabularx}

Tags: tabularx, ragged2e, cellspace

How to fix the error

> Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\ecolumn): `c' used.
>   \end{tabularx}

when using the column specifier `O` for the following?

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{makecell,ragged2e}
\usepackage[column=O]{cellspace}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\usepackage{tabularx,hyperref}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\Centering}X}

\begin{document}

    \begingroup
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \hypersetup{pageanchor=false}%

    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10mm}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10mm}

    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{%
            OY{1} Y{1} Y{1} Y{1}}
        \hline
        Question & Marks   & Score & \makecell[c]{Instructor\\ Signature}  \\
        \hline
        1\textsuperscript{st} & 30 & & \\
        \hline
        2\textsuperscript{nd} & 30 & & \\
        \hline
        3\textsuperscript{rd} & 30 & & \\
        \hline
        Total & 90 & &\\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \clearpage
    \endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with O{Y{1}} ?

Comment: @leandriis No, I haven't before your comment :).  You post it as an answer for the future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cellspace` documentation states

> To improve the spacing of your tables, you must change the table
>   preamble and prepend `S` to the column types `l`, `c`, `r`. Thesame holds for the
>   paragraph columns `p`, `m`, and `b`, except that they must be surrounded by an
>   extra pair of braces.

Since your ney column type `Y` is an altered version of `tabularx`'s `X` type columns, which in turn is derived from the `p` column type, You will also have so surround your `Y` column with an extra set of braces as follows:

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{%
            O{Y{1}} Y{1} Y{1} Y{1}}
```